# Getting my first provisional driving licence in uk using my BRP (new arrival non EU citizen)

Tags: united-kingdom, driving

Hi please need your help, I'm trying to get my first provisional driving licence in uk, given that I should show my adress for the last 3 years,considering I just moved here about few months ago, what can I do ?
I would appreciate a lot your help I'm not finding the asnwers anywehere else 
thank you very much cheers

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You're not required to show a UK address for the past 3 years. You'll need to write down your addresses for the past 3 years, wherever in the world they were. Could you explain more what your issue is?

Comment: @MJeffryes - I think that's an answer.

Comment: Thanks for being there to help !
it is because on the online system application it doesn't work for me when I introduce the post code of my adress lived oversea about the last 3 years. It tells me:
 Error: "" Postcodes should be in a valid format e.g AB12 3CD. Please try again."" 
Given my poste code is only Digits (5 Digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not required to show a UK address for the past 3 years. You'll need to provide your addresses for the past 3 years, wherever in the world they are.

Comment: Thanks for being there to help ! it is because on the online system application it doesn't work for me when I introduce the post code of my adress lived oversea about the last 3 years. It tells me: Error: "" Postcodes should be in a valid format e.g AB12 3CD. Please try again."" Given my poste code is only Digits (5 Digits)

Comment: I think I got another route through the online application system and it works !
thanks so much to everyone for your time and help ! cheers

Comment: @user16515 To help future expats with a similar problem, can you please post answer on how you "got another route through the online application system"?